# Enable X-Ray Active tracing of a lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I'm trying to add active tracing to 2 lambda functions, one in Node and one in Python. 
My service role has all the XRayWriteAccess permissions, I click the Advanced > Enable active tracing , see the info on permissions, click save, and see :

[image]

A web search did not return anything conclusive, any ideas?

Comment: Try using AWS CLI to enable the tracing and see what output is generated: `aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <name> --tracing-config Mode=Active`

Comment: Surprisingly, the only effect this command had was to enable the tracing without a hiccup. make it an answer if you want the points? Here's the output, sanitised : https://gist.github.com/xShirase/8c1a421b056272520388e3039cc27c21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your web console maybe was prefilling some form fields (I blame the browser for it). If you just want to enable X-Ray Active tracing for the function, make a call to [`update-function-configuration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html) with AWS CLI:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration \
    --function-name <name> \
    --tracing-config Mode=Active
```